# How to make a simple pointTowards() function in Roblox lua

Tags: math, lua, roblox, coordinate-systems

Specifically, I want to make a part point towards the players x, y, and z coordinates. Is there a math equation that I can use? Or maybe something along those lines?? Thank you

Comment: Yes, there is probably a math equation you can use.

Comment: consider reading the [Roblox documentation on Understanding CFrames](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Understanding-CFrame). It will help you understand how to manipulate a Part's CFrame property to have objects look at points. There is even a code sample that does what you are asking.

Comment: @Kylaaa I did try that but the documentation was very vague. Although, I still tried what I could find. Nothing.

Comment: @Kylaaa When I thought I couldn't scroll any further. Thank you so much! I don't know how I didn't see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
YourPart.CFrame = CFrame.lookAt(YourPart.Position, Player.Position)
```